# Html form - iframe not working in firefox but works in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a html table, form and a hidden iframe in my page. On onclick action of the table column(td), I am rendering a pdf document in the iframe.

In IE, this works fine on subsequent clicks. But in **Firefox**, it works only the first time and on subsequent clicks, iframe wont get refreshed with the latest data.

Here is my sample code:

HTML code:

```
<div id="pdfdiv" style="visibility: hidden">
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="auto" name="pdfViewer"></iframe>
</div>
```

JavaScript code calling iframe using form:

```
--
--
 pdfdiv.style.visibility = "visible";//also set height and width
--
document.forms1.target="pdfViewer"; 
document.forms1.action="URL";
document.forms1.submit();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

-Mango

Answer (score 0):

Instead of visibility: hidden, try "display: none" and "display: block"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the content of the frame is being cached. One way to solve it is if you have your server side code under control, add no-caching there:

```
<head>
<meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
</head>
```

another thing to do:

```
document.getElementById(FrameID).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```